# Trying to move the log file once logging has completed to a different location

Tags: python, file, logging, permissions, move

I am trying to create a log file where the python script is located. Once all the logging is done I would like to move the file to the folder where outputs are saved. I am getting the below error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\VI02080\Desktop\UAW work_V2\Humana\Python_Script\UAW_Humana_01.py", line 218, in 
os.rename(logfilepath, finallogfilepath)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\Users\VI02080\Desktop\UAW work_V2\Humana\Python_Script\UAW_BCBS_log_20231107.log' -> 'C:\Users\VI02080\Desktop\UAW work_V2\Humana\Python_Result\UAW_BCBS_log_20231107.log'

PS C:\Users\VI02080\Desktop\UAW work_V2>**

```
# ***************************************** set up logger file ****************************************
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
logfilename = f'UAW_BCBS_log_{current_date}.log'
logfilepath= os.path.join(mapping_filepath, logfilename)
log = loggersetup(__name__,logfilepath)

# ***************************************** Import Libraries ****************************************
import logging
import logging.handlers

# ***************************************** function start ****************************************
# Setup log function
def loggersetup(modulename,log_file_name):
    '''
    Function to set up a logger functionality
        @param : 
            modulename - module to initialise
            log_file_name - name of the log file 

        @return :
            logger - logger object 

    '''
    logger = logging.getLogger(modulename)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    
    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    return logger




#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__== "__main__":
   
   # start the timer
   start_time = time.time() 

   #start logging
   log.info('{} PROGRAM START {}'.format('********************', '**********************'))
   username = os.getenv("USERNAME") # get the user name who is running the script
   log.info('User is {}'.format(username))
   
   ouputpath = main_controlChecks() #------------------------------function call

   # stop the timer
   end_time = time.time()
   log.info('Execution time is %s seconds', (end_time - start_time))
   log.info('{} PROGRAM END {}'.format('********************', '**********************'))


   # shut down log file
   if (log.hasHandlers()):
        log.handlers.clear()
   del log 
   
   # move logfile to ouputfolder 
   finallogfilepath= os.path.join(ouputpath, logfilename)
   shutil.move(logfilepath, finallogfilepath)
```